# DevExpress grid's RowValidating event returning null on e.NewValues

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

From what I've been reading, e.NewValues should populate with the new value that was updated, for the FieldName passed to it. But I'm getting null each time.

[image]

And here's the debug view. I'm changing the value of the ShalePlay field and the RowValidating event is firing as expected. But checking the NewValue is returning null.

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Markup:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView
ID="gvLocation"
runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="esmdsLocation"
ClientInstanceName="gvLocation"
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
KeyFieldName="LocationPK"
Width="600px"
OnCellEditorInitialize="gvLocation_CellEditorInitialize"
OnCommandButtonInitialize="gvLocation_CommandButtonInitialize"
OnStartRowEditing="gvLocation_StartRowEditing"
OnRowValidating="gvLocation_RowValidating">

<%--  <ClientSideEvents BeginCallback="
                        function(s, e) {loadingPanel.Show();}"
    EndCallback="
                        function(s, e) {loadingPanel.Hide();}" />--%>
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
        <EditButton Visible="True">
        </EditButton>
        <NewButton Visible="True">
        </NewButton>
    </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="LocationPK" ReadOnly="True" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="1">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="gvLocation_LinkClick('<%# Container.VisibleIndex %>');"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LocationPK") %></a>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>

    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LocationName" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="2" />
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="FieldType" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="3" />
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="County" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="4" />
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="State" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5" />
    <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="ShalePlay" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="6" />
</Columns>
<Settings ShowFilterBar="Visible" ShowFilterRow="True" ShowGroupPanel="True" />
<SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
<SettingsLoadingPanel Mode="Disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of two things is most likely happening:

**Possiblity 1.** You're populating your GridView (binding data to it) on every page load, without using a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` filter.  This would cause your NewValues collection to be empty, because the Grid is freshly repopulated from the datasource.

You need to do your databinding within a block like this on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Where "BindGrid" above is whatever process / method / code you use to bind data to your aspxGridView.

Or **possibility 2.** "ShalePlay" is not the name of the field in the datasource that's populating your GridView. Note that that might be different than, for instance, the name of the column in your database (depending on how your GridView is populated).

For that, you need to check your datasource and make sure the field name is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I don't think it's issue two. I changed the FieldName to a different name, "Shale Play", just to test. I got a completely different error that time. And it actually said, "A field or property with name 'Shale Play' was not found in the selected data." For issue one, the data source is being bound at design time. We have an EntityServerModeDataSource control, which is bound to the DataSourceID property.

Comment: @ernest Oh, okay.  It would helpful if you edited your question to include the relevant markup (grid and datasource).